# Mostrar información de objeto dentro de arreglo en un div usando angular + firebase

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, firebase

tengo una base de datos creada en Firebase. Todo sale bien cuando hago una consulta para traerme los datos almacenados. Mi problema se presenta cuando deseo mostrar la información de un objeto JSON en el frontend usando angularfire2.

Les dejo un fragmento de código:

```
var apptelecapp = angular.module('appSPC8923712300', []);

apptelecapp.controller('spc8923712300', ['$scope',function($scope){
  //let referencia2 = firebase.database().ref('hggsfsdwwhf8262524588/');

  $scope.lista = []; //Acá se almacenará la información

  referencia.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
    $scope.base = snapshot.val();

    for(var i in $scope.base){
      $scope.lista.push([i, $scope.base[i]]);
    }

  }); 

}]);
```

Ahora en el archivo HTML cuando coloco {{lista}} me aparece vacío. No se si es porqué está dentro de una función

**¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos de $scope.lista en el div?**

Answer (score 0):

Para bindear un array en la vista, puedes usar la directiva ng-repeat. Como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in lista">
    {{item}} 
    <!-- Si se trata de un objeto, entonces debes indicar la propiedad que quieres imprimir. De otra forma te imprimira [object Object] -->
  </li>
</ul>
```